# How can I set up Reverse port forwarding with remote desktop over UDP(Not TCP)?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, port-forwarding, tunnel, reverse-tunnel

The scenarios is as following:

I have two computers, let's say one is work computer and one is home computer. The work computer is behind a firewall and I want to have access to port 3389 so I can have remote access to it. What I'm doing now is reverse port forwarding to my home computer. This works alright-ish. I also tried the VPN route, where I've set a VPN on my home router but there were some issues and I keep getting a broken link error (didn't bother too much with it, too many variables). Anyway, reverse port forwarding through SSH is ok, but I would like to be able to have RDPv8 to switch to UDP packets instead of TCP. I know there's a workaround with OpenSSH but I need to install cygwin and it's way to much work for very little benefit I think. So... finally, my question: Do you know any way do this reverse port-forwarding through UDP, encryption isn't important in this case (and please don't preach me about it) the only thing I care for is speed. Also, I've tested RDC from home to work through SSH and it feels slightly slower then when I RDC from work to home (without ssh in this case, and UDP connection is used).

Any ideas, suggestions, workarounds are welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: you write "to be able to have RDPv8 to switch to UDP packets instead of TCP...I know there's a workaround with OpenSSH "  out of interest, can you link to that?

Comment: Here it is. http://www.qcnetwork.com/vince/doc/divers/udp_over_ssh_tunnel.html Though you should note that it's considered unsafe because it's kinda UDP over TCP and TCP can break UDP packets.

Comment: Your title should mention UDP and SSH/RDP as that's crucial for the question.. I don't know which of these titles is more accurate to what you want to do, but  a title like "Can I do SSH with UDP?"  or "Can I do SSH and RDP, with UDP?"  or "Can I do SSH or RDP, with UDP?

Comment: The thing is I don't want to do it with SSH. I'm currently doing it with SSH but it's not necessary.

Comment: oh, ok reverse port forwarding with UDP not TCP, and encryption is not necessary. I understand exactly what you mean now, though I don't know

Comment: oh, ok reverse port forwarding with UDP not TCP, and encryption is not necessary. I understand exactly what you mean now, though I don't know. I once looked for a TCP port mapper mapper without enryption, though you want that but for UDP and with reverse, and with or without encryption.. very understandable, a great question. I suggest asking this question in bits and to linux gurus and miss out about RDP as RDP is only windows.  If I find anything i'll let you know. That said, just to be clear.. You seemed to say you want RDP over UDP,but you also seemed to say RDP over UDP is a workaround..

Comment: Why do you want RDP over UDP?   And if you already set RDP to be over UDP, what method did you use to do it?

Comment: Hey, sorry to answer so late. No, you can't set RDP to use TCP or UDP. RDPv8 switches to UDP when... I don't really know when, when Microsoft decided to. I want RDP over UDP because it feels more responsive even when the connection is worse. (3 lines signal on UDP vs 4 lines signal  on TCP - UDP wins in my opinion). And the only way I managed to get RDP to go through UDP was to connect directly but this was from WORK->HOME, I can't connect directly from HOME->WORK. I said it's a workaround because there's a way to tunnel UDP through ssh but according to what I've read it's kinda unsafe.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to setup OpenVPN as it's able to tunnel UDP traffic as well. I'll see how that works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11064/discussion-between-barlop-and-bogdan)

Comment: haven't tried that but yeah VPN i've heard encrypts the entire connection so indeed would include UDP. (btw if you have never tried cygwin, you should try it, it has openssh and probably openvpn. though where native is available many tend to choose native rather than cygwin and no doubt native is available here).

Comment: So in the end, the best thing so far I've managed to setup OpenVPN to do static tunnel (guide here http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html). When pinging my home computer from work directly I get 3-5ms response time and when pinging it through OpenVPN I get 4-6ms. It's completely unnoticeable. For even more speed you can disable encryption with "cypher none" in your config gile.